# EN version is getting added for new item which is being created in any other language programatically

Tags: multilingual, versions

I am creating an item as well as its version in specific language (let's say Arabic) and then creating a clone of the newly created item in that particular language (Arabic). The issue is that the item as well as it's clone both are getting created in "en" as well as in "ar" language. However, I don't want the "en" version. Not sure why the English version is being added.

I also have tried to remove the unwanted version but this is not feasible for us because of performance issue as we are going to have lot many items.

Below is code snippet for example.

```
Sitecore.Globalization.Language language = LanguageManager.GetLanguage("ar"); //arabic language
using (new LanguageSwitcher(language))
{
    var  videoItem = ItemManager.AddFromTemplate("SampleName", "<<template ID>>", "<<parent item>>", "<<GUID>>");
    videoItem = videoItem.Database.GetItem(videoItem.ID, language);
    if (videoItem.Versions.Count < 1)
    {
        videoItem = videoItem.Versions.AddVersion();
    }
    videoItem.CloneTo("<<sitecore item where the item to be cloned>>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemManager.AddFromTemplate` method creates an item with 1 version already. And from what I remember, it creates the child item in the language of the `destination` parameter (3rd one), where you pass `parent` item.

It means that if you pass `en` version of the `parent` to the `AddFromTemplate` method, it will create `en` version of the item.

Try to get `ar` version of the `parent` item first and pass that item to `AddFromTemplate` method:

```
var arParent = parent.Database.GetItem(parent.ID, arLanguage);
var videoItem = ItemManager.AddFromTemplate("SampleName", "<<template ID>>", arParent , "<<GUID>>");
```

Comment: Thanks @Marek, now parent item is creating in arabic only. However, it's still creating clone in all languages.

Comment: The item which is passed in `videoItem.CloneTo("<<sitecore item where the item to be cloned>>");` method should also be in `arLanguage`.

Comment: Thanks @Marek. It's working fine for cloning the item in one language. However, when I am creating clone of the same videoItem(under other parent) in second language. i.e. "fr" . Then again its creating "en" version of the same cloned item. So, after this step - the cloned item is in three language version ("ar", "fr", "en")